# Problem 20.3 Munkres, Show that metric of a metric space is continous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be a metric space with a metric $d$, show that $d: \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

I struggled with the solution a bit and looked in an online solution manual. I wasn't able to understand why the solution worked. The solution used was outlined as follows:

- Let $U=d^{-1}(\mathcal{a},\mathcal{b})$ and $\mathcal{x}\times \mathcal{y} \in U$
- Create an open set in $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}$, $ B_d(x, \epsilon)\times B_d(y, \epsilon)$
- Show that this set is a neighborhood of $\mathcal{x}\times \mathcal{y}$ in $XxX$ contained in $U$
- Therefore $U$ is open in $XxX$

This seems to me like we are only proving a subset of $U$ is open. Why does this hold for the entire set $U$? Is this because we can do this "infinitely" many times to "reconstruct" $U$?

Comment: Open intervals form a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ so it suffices to only consider pre-images of those.

Comment: A set $U$ is open iff for every point $p\in U$ there exists an open neighborhood of $p$ contained in $U$. That is what is being used in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This seems to me like we are only proving a subset of $U$ is open. Why does this hold for the entire set $U$? Is this because we can do this "infinitely" many times to "reconstruct" $U$?

Yes, we can reconstruct $U$ with this. We just showed that given $v\in U$ there is some open subset $W$ such that $v\in W\subseteq U$. Denote this $W$ by $W_v$ to be clear that it depends on $v$. So since $v$ was chosen arbitrarily (just like in your case $x\times y$ is chosen arbitrarily) we have the collection $\{W_v\}_{v\in U}$ of open subsets. What is left is to notice that

$$U=\bigcup_{v\in U}W_v$$

and so $U$ is a union of open subsets, therefore open.